# How to get my linux box sound and microphone path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

In linux how can i find what is my sound card path and microphone path? Some application is using `/dev/dsp` but how to make sure what is mine?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is't a programming question see the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Because you program using a certain OS doesn't mean any question regarding the OS are 'programming questions' http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You have several questions which have been migrated from StackOverflow to other places, you should know this by now.

Comment: `Is there any case like it blocks from other visitors? ` I don't believe so

Comment: understand why there are different sections for different types of questions. Maybe you should do more research via google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dev/dsp` and `/dev/mixer` are devices for the OSS3 sound system. The device paths are always the same on all systems.

However, due to the many limits of OSS3, almost all modern Linux distributions use ALSA for sound, which doesn't have `dsp` and `mixer` devices. It's possible to use [OSS emulation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/alsa-oss) in several ways:

- #### User-mode, PulseAudio:

  PulseAudio comes with OSS emulation libraries. Run your program through `padsp`:

  ```
  padsp ./sjphone
  ```
- #### User-mode, direct ALSA:

  Install the *alsa-oss* package, then run your program through `aoss`:

  ```
  aoss ./sjphone
  ```

  This works on PulseAudio systems too (although maybe not as well as `padsp`).
- #### Kernel-mode:

  Load the *`snd-pcm-oss`* and *`snd-mixer-oss`* kernel modules, then run your program normally:

  ```
  sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss
  sudo modprobe snd-mixer-oss
  ./sjphone
  ```

  This method is **not recommended** – especially avoid it on PulseAudio systems, since kernel OSS emulation may conflict with how PulseAudio manages the hardware. User-mode `padsp` or `aoss` is usually the better choice.

Comment: Thank you. Its very nice answer and very confusing one of mine. I used "aoss ./sjphone", and i can use the slider of microphone only, but i cant use the speaker slider, which is disabled still. Is that has to do with aoss still or ./sjphone itself?

Comment: Thanks again. Its just working super cool. You are genius!!

Comment: Of note: The /dev/dsp does not show up in directory listings, but can be opened for reading or writing.  Try `padsp cat /dev/dsp >temp.wav` for recording and `padsp bash -c 'cp temp.wav /dev/dsp'` for playback.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/dsp is the standard device in Linux for outputting or recording sound. There isn't a special device path for your soundcard or microphone.

Comment: But as you can see here it using /dev/dsp. But i do not have any mic/headphone sounds for this. What else i can apply instead of /dev/dsp in that case? e.g: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7WPVw.png

Comment: /dev/dsp does not exist as a file on my system, despite having and successfully using a microphone to capture audio.